# Octave Change UIControl Position

Tags: octave, uicontrol

The following is example code from Matlab. It doesn't run in Octave. The code is:

```
f = figure;
b = uicontrol(f,'Style','pushbutton');
b.Position = [100 100 50 20];
```

It is from the online documentation: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.control.uicontrol-properties.html

In Octave, I get: error: scalar cannot be indexed with .

What change must be made to make this run in Octave?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATLAB introduced the second version of the handle graphics system (HG2) a couple of years ago. Octave still uses the old system.

Every time you see `handle.propery`, you are dealing with HG2. In the original system, we used `get(handle,'property')` and `set(handle,'property',newvalue)`. Note that MATLAB will not deprecate this original syntax any time soon, it is perfectly valid to use both forms with the newer versions of MATLAB. Thus, the `set` and `get` functions are to be preferred for compatibility reasons.

So you can replace

```matlab
b.Position = [100 100 50 20];
```

with

```matlab
set(b,'Position',[100 100 50 20]);
```

Comment: Thanks. That works perfectly. It also works both ways in Matlab.

Comment: @kainaw Indeed, the old syntax has not been removed, and will not be removed in the foreseeable future. I've added a sentence to address that.